# Missing creative spec facebook

Tags: facebook-graph-api, facebook-php-sdk

I'm trying to create an ad using the php sdk.

I can create the campaign, targeting, adset, and the creative (which returns a creative_id that I can validate using the graph explorer).

But when I finally run the code to create the ad itself, I get an exception that looks like this:

```
   "error_user_title" => "Missing creative spec"
    "error_user_msg" => "No creative spec found for given adgroup."
```

I just can't find anything referring to this error.

Below is the relevant portion of my code:

```
    $link_data = new AdCreativeLinkData();
    $link_data->setData(array(
        AdCreativeLinkDataFields::LINK => $route,
        AdCreativeLinkDataFields::MESSAGE => $petition_statement,
        AdCreativeLinkDataFields::NAME => $banner_title,
        AdCreativeLinkDataFields::IMAGE_HASH => $image_hash,
    ));


    $object_story_spec = new AdCreativeObjectStorySpec();
    $object_story_spec->setData(array(
        AdCreativeObjectStorySpecFields::PAGE_ID => $pageid,
        AdCreativeObjectStorySpecFields::INSTAGRAM_ACTOR_ID=>$instagram_id,
        AdCreativeObjectStorySpecFields::LINK_DATA=>$link_data
    ));


    $creative = new AdCreative(null,$account_id);
    $creative->setData(array(
        AdCreativeFields::TITLE => $banner_title,
        AdCreativeFields::BODY => $banner_subtitle,
        AdCreativeFields::IMAGE_HASH => $image_hash,
        AdCreativeFields::OBJECT_TYPE => 'SHARE',
        AdCreativeFields::OBJECT_STORY_SPEC=>$object_story_spec

    ));

    $creative->create();


    echo 'Creative ID: '.$creative->id . "\n";

    $ad = new Ad(null, $account_id);
    $ad->setData(array(
        AdFields::NAME => $short_name,
        AdFields::ADSET_ID => $adset->id,
        AdFields::CREATIVE => $creative,
        AdFields::TRACKING_SPECS => array(array(
            'action.type' => 'offsite_conversion',
            'fb_pixel' => $pixel_code,
        ))

    ));
    $ad->create(array(Ad::STATUS_PARAM_NAME => Ad::STATUS_PAUSED));
```

Appreciate any help.

Comment: Any update on this? How did you resolve it?

Answer (score 2):

I've often said that the only skill you need to be a successful developer is the ability to agonize over a problem for days, read through source code, google it, refactor, rewrite and then realize you forgot something fucking obvious.

```
    AdFields::CREATIVE => $creative,
```

should read

```
    AdFields::CREATIVE => $creative->id,
```

But the ability to persist isn't the skill you need.  The real skill is to somehow resist the overwhelming urge to chuck your computer out the window and do something productive with your life instead.

Comment: In order to be a successful developer, documentation should be correct. The sample code on Facebook's site is wrong, your correction is... correct :) https://developers.facebook.com/docs/marketing-api/reference/adgroup

Comment: That is what i have been feeling as well. Facebook documentation feel very unclear to me.

Answer (score 2):

After hours of testing it seems Trevor's answer is incorrect. This is the right syntax:

```
AdFields::CREATIVE => array('creative_id'=>$creative->id)
```